# Is it good practice to make multiple classes Serializable?

Tags: java, serializable

I was wondering about how to serialize nested classes properly.
My problem is that there is one class that has a list of data that I need to serialize. The data though, is an object of many other classes. For example if Test1 is my data class, it has Test1a and others.

The error that I get if I don't write "implements Serializable" is that it is 
"java.io.NotSerializableException".

Should I just "implement Serializable" to all my classes then?

```
public class Test1 implements Serializable {
     public void save() {
         //some code to save 
     }
     public void load() {
         //some code to load
     }
     public class Test1a {   
          //something related
     }
}
```

Comment: You should add `implements Serializable` to all the classes that you want to serialize. And don't add it to any that you don't want to serialize.

Comment: Read Effective Java from Joshua Bloch, it contains a great deal on information about serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you wan't to serialize a class, all the classes that it is dependent on should also be Serializable if you want to serialize them. If you don't wish to Serialize a member of a class, mark it as transient. When you mark something as transient, it will not be serialized. This means that when you deserialze an Object and it has a transient member, that transient member will get a default value.

Comment: Thanks, that's everything I needed. I appreciate it.